# Adicionar e remover required JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma pergunta de radio button:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1">
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="dirar" value="1">
                Sim
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="dirar" value="0">
                Não
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    // Validação de erro caso não tenha selecionado uma opção msg = "Campo Obrigatório"
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label id="dirar-error" class="input-error" for="dirar" style="border: none; color: red;"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Se `name="dirar"` for selecionado `'0' = não`, preciso de uma validação que adicione `required="required"` a uma outra questão que está abaixo:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1">
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="isubrar" value="1">
                Sim
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="isubrar" value="0">
                Não
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Resumindo, se `name="dirar"` for `'0' = Não` o segundo radio button `name="isubrar"` torna-se um campo obrigatório ou se `name="dirar"`for `'1' = Sim` `name="isubrar"`não será um campo obrigatório.

Comment: O que você já tentou? Recebeu algum erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue uma implementação funcional:

```js
$(":radio[name='dirar']").change(function(){
  if($(this).val() === "0") {
    $(":radio[name='isubrar']").attr("required", "required");
  } else {
    $(":radio[name='isubrar']").removeAttr("required");
  }
  
  console.log($(":radio[name='isubrar']").attr("required"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1">
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="dirar" value="1">
                Sim
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="dirar" value="0">
                Não
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1">
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="isubrar" value="1">
                Sim
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="isubrar" value="0">
                Não
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Funcionou Perfeitamente @Marcell_Alves, Obrigado!